# Capture 2nd entry from database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I'm quite new to the programming world and have become stuck with querying a database in C#.

I am trying to return a date and an Int32 from the second entry in a database using the code below:

```
OleDbCommand com101 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 2 [Flight_Date], [No_Launches] FROM Flights WHERE [Claimed_By_ID] = ? ORDER BY [Flight_Date] DESC LIMIT 1,1", Program.DB_CONNECTION);
com101.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", 451));
OleDbDataReader dr101 = com101.ExecuteReader();
```

when I run the code I get an error saying there is a problem with the `Syntax error in ORDER BY clause.`

Can anyone spot what I am missing?

Cheers

Comment: `= ?` looks suspect. What are you trying to compare for equality here, the string `'?'`, or is that a wildcard you should be replacing with something else entirely?

Comment: TOP 2 Actually selects both of the values from that table. You should iterate over OleDbDataReader to actuallly get the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT TOP 2 [Flight_Date], [No_Launches]
FROM Flights
WHERE [Claimed_By_ID] = ?
ORDER BY [Flight_Date] DESC
LIMIT 1,1;
```

You need to decide which database you are using.  Some support `TOP`; some support `LIMIT`.  Based on your error and the use of the square braces, I would guess that you are using SQL Server/Sybase and should remove the `LIMIT` clause:

```
SELECT TOP 2 [Flight_Date], [No_Launches]
FROM Flights
WHERE [Claimed_By_ID] = ?
ORDER BY [Flight_Date] DESC;
```

If this is true, you should change the tag on the question from "mysql" to "sql-server".

EDIT:

To get the second entry, I think you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (SELECT TOP 2 [Flight_Date], [No_Launches]
      FROM Flights
      WHERE [Claimed_By_ID] = ?
      ORDER BY [Flight_Date] DESC
     ) as t
ORDER BY Flight_Date ASC
```

Comment: Hi im using a MSAccess Database which I think is MySQL,                   If I remove the LIMIT how can I get only the second entry?